# How do you reference Ranges in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, runtime-error, range, vba

I have a named range in Excel that has some data I want to process in a subroutine or function, however I'm having a hard time figuring out how to reference individual parts of the range. I'm trying to use the `Cells` function, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Sub sub1()
x = Range("Test")

For Each i In x
    v = x.Cells(i, 1)
    calculate(v)
Next i

End Sub
```

As of right now, the named range "Test" is named for A1:A18 and the calculate function hasn't been written. Using the debug tools in VBA, the program throws an error at the `v = x.Cells(i,1)` line: "Run-time error '424': Object required"

There seems to be something obvious I'm missing. Perhaps there's a way to convert a named range to an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is in Siddharth Rout answer ; I'll just go into more detailed explanation.

The flaw is that x is undeclared, therefore VB uses a `Variant`. You need x to be a `Range` type, so you can refer to its `Cells` property. Therefore you should declare it so.

Insert `Dim x as Range` as first line of `sub1`. You will then have to use the `Set` keyword to assign to x : `Set x = Range("test")`

`Set` is the syntax used to assign objects.

Also, the `Cells` property is the default property of `Range`. Therefore it is not required to write it explicity.

```
For each i in x
```

assigns to i a `Range` object which is the i'th cell of range x. So you can apply calculate on i.

Now one last thing : `Calculate` can be applied to a single cell or to a Range. Therefore, x.Calculate would work (whithout the need for a loop).

This gives :

```
Sub sub1()
  Dim x as Range
  Dim i as Range
  Set x = Range("Test")

  For Each i In x
      i.Calculate
  Next i

End Sub
```

or simpler:

```
Sub sub1()
  Dim x as Range
  Set x = Range("Test")

  x.Calculate

End Sub
```

if "Calculate" is a user-function :

```
Sub sub1()
  Dim x as Range
  Dim i as Range
  Set x = Range("Test")

  For Each i In x
      Call CalculateMyPurpose(i)
  Next i

End Sub

Sub CalculateMyPurpose(myCell as Range)
  'Do something on myCelll
End Sub
```

NB : I would suggest you declare all variables. This will make sure they have the type you want them to. To enforce variable declarations, write `Option Explicit` as 1st line of the module.

Comment: So, if I want to perform calculations on each cell individually, such as checking what the cell contains before doing something to it's contents, would it be better to use the first example? Also, in your example, you declare i as a Range. In my mind I visualize i as an element of x, which would make it a Cell within the range x. I'm not sure I understand why there would be ranges within the range x. Can you clarify this point? Finally, you have i.Calculate; is this the same as Calculate(i)? What if I need to pass Calculate further variables?

Comment: Yes, better use the first example. About i being a "Cell" : Excel does not have a specific object for "Cell". A Cell is simply a 1x1 Range (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx)). Finally, about "Calculate(i)" : This is not a valid syntax. The valid syntax is i.Calculate (Again see Excel help or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff195517.aspx)).

Comment: + 1 for going the extra mile :)

Comment: About your purpose and "Calculate" : I see now that you intend to write your own "Calculate" sub, not to use the embeeded "Calculate". I would suggest you use another name for it. (such as "CalculateMyPurpose"). Then, as you rightly wrote, you have to use "Call CalculateMyPurpose(i, some_argument, ...)". (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `Cells` :)

Is this what you are doing (UNTESTED)?

```
Sub sub1()
    Dim cl As Range, nmRange As Range

    Set nmRange = Range("Test")

    For Each cl In nmRange
        calculate (cl)
    Next cl
End Sub

'~~> Some sub
Sub calculate(rng As Range)

End Sub
```